# php ошибка mysqli_nums_rows()

Tags: php, sql

Переделываю на сайт свои исходники с mysql на mysqli.
Изначально все рабочее, почти все переделал, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. При отработке данного скрипта:

```
    <?php 
   session_start();
   $dbhost = 'mysql.hostinger.com.ua';
   $dbuser = 'u978123852_root';
   $dbpass = 'hunter999love';
   $dbname = 'u978123852_root';
   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn )
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *  FROM `Users` WHERE `Username` = '$username'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1)
    {
        echo "No user";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "User is ";
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['login_user']= $username;

        if ($row[5] == $password)
        {
            echo "entered as ";
            if ($row[6] == "admin")
            {
                echo "admin ";
                echo $_SESSION['login_user'];
                echo " . ";
                echo "<a href='admin.html'>Go to admin tools </a>";
                echo "or wait auto-redirect.";
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=admin.html" />';
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "user ";
                echo $_SESSION['login_user'];
                echo " . ";
                echo "<a href='index.html'>Go to main page </a>";
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=index.html" />';
                echo "or wait auto-redirect.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            "wrote incorrect password";
        }
    }
?>
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/u978123852/public_html/php/login.php on line 21
```

Как я понял, происходит она при не правильном запросе, но запрос рабочий - на локальной версии работает отлично, к БД подключился на сайте правильно, ибо другие скрипты отрабатывают.

Comment: 1. Рекомендую сменить пароли. 2. Проблема не в mysqli_num_rows, а в mysqli_query, которая возвращает false, а не mysqli_result.

Comment: 1)Пароли у пользователей? 2)Как докопаться до этой ошибки?

Comment: @VyacheslavMartynenko докопаться до ошибки - всегда следует с самого простого. вместо `'$username'` подставьте реальное имя пользователя к примеру. `Username` точно начинается с заглавной буквы? `$conn` точно ли содержит подключение или там может тоже ничего нет

Comment: $conn проверил, $username не пустой, Username с большой. Ошибка даже при просто селекте всех пользователей.

Comment: @VyacheslavMartynenko К сожалению вряд ли еще что-то можно сказать. Раз на каждом этапе все работает даже со статическими данными и даже `$conn` 100% работает, возможно, следует тогда обратиться в службу поддержки хостинга. Может они что-то разъяснят и что-то не так у них.? Кстати у вас ошибка.. надо `mysqli_error()` а не `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` может возвращаться `FALSE` в случае неудачи, так что лучше сначала проверять на успех. Даже в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) так написано в примерах.

```
//...
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *  FROM `Users` WHERE `Username` = '$username'");
if($result) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1)
    {
        echo "No user";
    }
    //...
} else {
   // обработка ошибки
}
```